# noexcept specifier depending on a template class member function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, noexcept

In the following example, I have an algorithm depending on another algorithm through a template.

```
class absolute_distance
{
    public:
        absolute_distance() noexcept {}
        ~absolute_distance() noexcept {}
        double compute(double x1, double x2) const noexcept { return std::abs(x1 - x2); }
};

template <typename D = absolute_distance>
class Algorithm
{
    private:
        D d;
    public:
        Algorithm() : d() {}
        Algorithm(D const& d_) : d(d_) {}
        ~Algorithm() {}
        double execute(double x1, double x2) const { return this->d.compute(x1,x2) + 1.0; }
};
```

Now, I would like to specify *noexcept* specifiers on the functions of my class `Algorithm`. Of course, it depend on the *noexcept* specifications of the template class `D`.

For the constructors, it's quite easy, it depend on the constructor of `D` actually used:

```
Algorithm() noexcept(noexcept(D())) : d() {}
Algorithm(D const& d_) noexcept(noexcept(D(d_))) : d(d_) {}
```

For the function `execute` it seems more complicated... I don't know how to specify the noexcept-ness due the following problem: I can write

```
double execute(double x1, double x2) const noexcept(noexcept(D().compute(x1,x2))) { return this->d.compute(x1,x2) + 1.0; }
```

to check the noexceptness of the function `compute` used in the function `execute`, but this checks the function `compute` AND the constructor of `D`, and maybe the constructor of `D` could throw.

**Is there a way to only check the *noexcept* specification of `D::compute` ?**

Comment: This compiles (but I am not sure enough about it to post an answer) `double execute(double x1, double x2) const noexcept(noexcept(d.compute(x1,x2))) { return d.compute(x1,x2) + 1.0; }` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/KGha6TnzT

Comment: @RichardCritten it works for me too. I tried with `this->d` and it was refused. But I did not tired without `this`. Thanks.